# How to decrease the size of docker image?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, tensorflow2.0

It is of 2.2 GB now any one know how to reduce this docker image??
i have tried to reduce the size by checking with different python version but that also didn't
make any big difference!!

Dockerfile:

```
From python:3.6-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

ADD text_extraction /app/

ADD text_extraction/text_extraction/requirements.txt  requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 -y

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

docker-compose.yml-
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
    enter code here
```

Comment: How much disk space does `text_extraction` occupy?

Comment: There are many things that can be optimized: `pip install --no-cache-dir …`, all `apt` command in one `RUN` including removing the database.

Comment: Images based on Alpine Linux are usually a bit smaller. Try basing on `python:3.6-alpine`

Comment: Remove `ADD text_extraction /app/`, share your `requirements.txt`. After above, tell what's your image size now, and then tell what's your target image size. Then folks have a reproduceable minimal example to help you. Otherwise, all you received is general suggestion.

Comment: @michaelRuth  text_extraction size was 2.MB.

Comment: @HansKilian have tried python-alpine but there were lots of issues while building numpy library.

Comment: @Aayusmishra with an app size of 2MB you need to look at the dependencies of the project for improvement. Eliminate unnecessary dependencies. There may be potential to reduce final image size by using a multi-stage build. Regardless, I'll need the requirements.txt file in order to do anything further with this.